# Key not valid for use in specified state in RSA encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

here is my code.get error in encryption method
encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding); 
The method throws "Key not valid for use in specified state."

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        var rsaKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa);
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        var writer2 = new StringWriter();
        var pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
        var pemWriter2 = new PemWriter(writer2);
        pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Public);
        pemWriter2.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Private);
        string Pub = writer.ToString();
        string Prv = writer2.ToString();
        plaintext = ByteConverter.GetBytes(txtplain.Text);
        encryptedtext = Encryption(plaintext, Pub, false);
    }
```

get error here when encrypt data using by RSA encryption method.here pass DATA as a byte and RSA public key as a string.after that convert it to RSAParanetrs "RSA.ImportParameters(GetRSAParameters(RSAKey));"
then encrypt data get this error.

```
    static public byte[] Encryption(byte[] Data, string RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(GetRSAParameters(RSAKey));
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding); // get error "Key not valid for use in specified state"
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static RSAParameters GetRSAParameters(string pPublicKey)
    {
        byte[] lDer; 
        int lBeginStart = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".Length;
        int lEndLenght = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-------".Length;
        string KeyString = pPublicKey.Substring(lBeginStart, (pPublicKey.Length - lBeginStart - lEndLenght));
        lDer = Convert.FromBase64String(KeyString);
        RSAParameters lRSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();
        lRSAKeyInfo.Modulus = GetModulus(lDer);
        lRSAKeyInfo.Exponent = GetExponent(lDer);

        return lRSAKeyInfo;
    }
    private static byte[] GetModulus(byte[] pDer)
    {
        string lModulus = BitConverter.ToString(pDer).Replace("-", "").Substring(58, 256);
        return StringHexToByteArray(lModulus);
    }


    private static byte[] GetExponent(byte[] pDer)
    {
        int lExponentLenght = pDer[pDer.Length - 3];
        string lExponent = BitConverter.ToString(pDer).Replace("-", "").Substring((pDer.Length * 2) - lExponentLenght * 2, lExponentLenght * 2);

        return StringHexToByteArray(lExponent);
    }


    public static byte[] StringHexToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: The padding mode and the key does not agree.  To make it harder to for hackers to decrypt a message the key size can be hidden.  So you can have a key that is 220 bytes and then pad the key with random data so the key would look like 256 bytes.  Some encryption modes you padding and other do not.  Your error is due size of the key your are using and the options in RSA are not the same for the padding settings.

Comment: You don't really implement DER decoding. This is very dangerous, also because DER may use dynamically sized integers. As it is stated, it is not clear if the components are correctly retrieved; likely they are not.

Comment: actually how can i solve it ?is it possible to encrypt large data using this?please explain me if possible with coding example.